# Hadoop write output into a txt file

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am thinking how to write the output of Hadoop into a txt file, instead of writing into HDFS.
For example, I put the following code:

```
    // Create the job specification object
    Job job1 = new Job();
    job1.setJarByClass(Main.class);
    job1.setJobName("Day Measurment");

    // Setup input and output paths
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job1, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job1, new Path(args[1]));

    // Set the Mapper and Reducer classes
    job1.setMapperClass(DayMapper.class);
    job1.setReducerClass(LogReducer.class);

    // Specify the type of output keys and values
    job1.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job1.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

    // Wait for the job to finish before terminating
    job1.waitForCompletion(true);

    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("hadoop.csv");
    pw.println("abc");
    pw.close();
```

After I test my program, Hadoop works fine but I only get the hadoop.csv and no content inside. It is an empty file, no "abc" inside.

Could anybody tell me why? or tell me how to print the output into a regular file (.csv or .log), instead of into the HDFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PrintWriter object that is created does not use flush() by default. To turn this on, you can add a second paramenter to the constructor when creating the PrintWriter.

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw,true);
```

If you do not want to do that, you should simply be able to use the `flush()`-method instead

```
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("hadoop.csv");
        pw.println("abc");
        pw.flush();    
        pw.close();
```

Using `flush()` will ensure that any data that is to be written, doesn't get stuck in any internal buffer but simply pushed out onto the underlying output stream.

Take a look at this: [PrintWriter - Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("hadoop.csv");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

        pw.println("abc");

        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        fw.close();
```